# Eclipse Server Services encounters an error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, apache-axis

Note: Yes I have followed all of the other similar issues, I've downloaded 10+ .jars and tossed them into the lib file. nothing worked.

Note2: I am using eclipse 2020, jdk1.8, tomcat7.0.107, axis2-1.7.9

I have no idea what I'm doing but my university teacher says I need to follow this YouTube guide from 2014 for my 2021 IWS class.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgY0pLadraE
Unfortunately, everytime when I get to the 1:20 mark where I run my method on the server I get this ridiculous error.

```
 Jan 23, 2021 10:02:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/7.0.107
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 18 2020 12:18:55 UTC
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 7.0.107.0
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507\jre
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           15.0.1+9-18
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.107
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.107
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Users/Johnathan Nichols/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/Johnathan Nichols/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507/jre/bin;C:/Users/JOHNAT~1/AppData/Local/Temp/eoi6AB9.tmp//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/JOHNAT~1/AppData/Local/Temp/eoi6AB9.tmp//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507/jre/bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Java\jdk1.8\bin;C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.8;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;;C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\Downloads;;C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\Downloads;;.]
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 361 ms
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.107
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase$1 (file:/C:/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.107/lib/catalina.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.registerAsParallelCapable()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Johnathan Nichols\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\AddServiceServer\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[WARN] Web application uses org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet; please update web.xml to use org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet instead
[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer; see debug logs for more details
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1184)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1078)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5680)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1795)
    ... 24 more

Jan 23, 2021 10:02:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [AxisAdminServlet] in web application [/AddServiceServer] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1795)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1184)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1078)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5680)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Jan 23, 2021 10:02:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1539 ms
[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer; see debug logs for more details
Jan 23, 2021 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1184)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1795)
    ... 29 more

Jan 23, 2021 10:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [AxisServlet]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1795)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1184)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Also, I get this error

```
    HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [AxisServlet] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [AxisServlet] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)



Root Cause 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:622)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)



Root Cause 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1795)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:622)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)



Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Apache Tomcat/7.0.107

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundException` usually mean that your are missing a library. In your case the classes in the `org.apache.ws.commons.schema` are part of [XmlSchema.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.commons.schema/XmlSchema).

Check out the dependencies of your version of Axis2, e.g. on [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-kernel) and add the appropriate version of `XmlSchema.jar` to your project.

**Edit**: you can also download the entire [Axis2 binary distribution](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html) and add all jars to your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

A better alternative would be to use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/) as your build tool. This way you'll never miss a dependency.

Comment: I just downloaded xmlschema-2.2.5 from your link but it came as a folder instead of a .jar. When I added it to my project it showed me a red x on the folder and a few files inside but when I clicked on the red files they displayed no errors and only showed me images of a webpage.

I looked at the maven repository link and I found my axis2-1.7.9 file but I didn't see anything that linked it to the XmlSchema version.

Where can I get the .jar of XmlSchema? 
Should I drag and drop it into WebContent-Web-Inf-lib?

Comment: On the page for [axis2-kernel-1.7.9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-kernel/1.7.9) you'll see it need `xmlschema-core-2.2.1`. You can download the jar from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ws/xmlschema/xmlschema-core/2.2.1/).