# Eclipse Server Error with tomcat and axis2

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, apache-axis

I keep getting these errors in eclipse and I've scoured the internet and none of the listed fixes help.

If you need more information to answer my question then please let me know and I will find it.

Please submit all answers in plain English with links or I probably won't understand.

The package javax.xml.stream is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml

Comment: Please don't post your questions multiple times. It **is** the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having problems with the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), you can:

- either change your Eclipse project compliance to Java 8: choose "Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries", select JRE System Library, "Edit..." and choose *"Java SE-1.8"* as execution environment.
- or find which package is both in the JRE and classpath (read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571046/eclipse-is-confused-by-imports-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)). You just need to press `Ctrl+Shift+o` and type `javax.xml.stream`. You'll see that the package is in both the JRE and `geronimo-stax-api`. Delete the latter from your classpath.

Comment: @Karl, based on your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65860908/11748454) you have the entire Axis2 distribution on your classpath. Remove `geronimo-stax-api*jar`.